# Ionic can i get round input

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need round input in ionic and if possible to use Floating something like this in the image. Its very easy in Flutter but dont know how can i do this in ionic. Or if just possible to make it round input ? 
Here is image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1kiB.gif)

Comment: tell me if my component was ok.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that, you need to create your own component or get one from GitHub or Codepen or somewhere else. ionic does not provide anything like this.

---

#### Edited:

I made a component for you and I put it on Codepen. You just have to convert jQuery to your framework syntax.

[Click to View on Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/mahdizarei0614/pen/ExPVvRR)

Here is the component:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: #eee;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.container {
  width: 380px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  padding: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09804) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: block;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #636363;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 1000px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.stylee {
  top: -20px;
  transform: scale(.75);
  left: -2px;
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).prev().addClass('stylee');
}).blur(function() {
  if($(this).val())
    {
      $(this).prev().addClass('stylee');
    }
  else
  {
  $(this).prev().removeClass('stylee');
  }
});
```